# A Haskell interpreter /w type definitions

Tags: haskell, interpreter, ghci, hugs

Is there a Haskell interpreter that accepts type definitions or preferably all kinds of statements?

I've already tried `ghci` and `hugs` and none of these does that. Is there some particular reason that this is hard/impossible?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Though I think HBC was able to accept arbitrary Haskell statements.  Note that you can't just provide a type definition on its own in ghci as there won't be an attached function for it, though `let f x = x + 1 :: (Num a) => a -> a` should work.

Comment: I share your pain. I have tons of `Test.hs` hanging around.  Even worse, the ghci console doesn't deal with paste action correctly, at least on my system (bug I just reported).

Comment: @ivanm Actually, at this moment I'm just starting out and not yet trying to do anything particular. Just got me wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, the answer to this has been that code written at an interactive prompt lives inside the IO monad. It's as if there's a shadow `main = do` hiding behind the `Prelude>`. Think about it that way, and the absence of type declarations and top level declaration syntax makes sense, as do all the `let` statements.

But Ptival is right: it looks like we won't have to worry about any of that soon.

Answer (score 13):

It seems that it will soon be fixed in GHCi, see:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4929

Comment: Indeed. It's already possible in HEAD, and the feature will be in 7.4.